# Getting specific column in Ebean play framework 2.0

Tags: jpa, playframework, ebean

I am trying to get a list of unique names from the **name** column in my table.

```
List<String> li =  Ebean.find(User.class).where().?
```

How would I go about this?

For example if my table looked something like:

```
insert into users (name, age, height) values ('John', 19, 187);
insert into users (name, age, height) values ('Sam', 24, 160);
insert into users (name, age, height) values ('John', 21, 177);
```

I would want my list to look like

```
['John', 'Sam']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `li` array as empty and then fill it by iteration:

```
List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();

for(User user: User.find.select("name").findList()) {
    li.add(user.name);
}


return li;
```